# Check whether a user posted on facebook and twitter

Tags: .net, facebook, twitter, network-programming

We have an application written in C# .Net. 
We would like to offer our users free premium subscriptions to our services, in return for posting about us on twitter and Facebook.

To do that, currently, from inside our application, I simply open a browser component (Winforms WebBrowser), pointing to:
"http://twitter.com/home?status=Check out..."

and after that to:
"http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=Our Company..."

and let the user perform the posts by himself.

Is there a way I could make sure the user actually posted? Perhaps also check if the user indeed mentioned our company or changed the text we provided?

Thanks,
Arie

Comment: Any new information on this? I have the same requirements and the given answer is less than optimal...

Answer (score 1):

The only way to truly be sure is to authenticate the user using OAuth and post to Twitter using [POST statuses/update](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update). For pretty good results though you can include a hashtag and use the [Streaming API](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api) to track tweets containing the hashtag.